# Mdx query incosistent with cube browser

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have built a multidimensional `SSAS` cube with some calculations. I have a calculated member in which I use the the `parallelperiod` function to calculate the previous month value according to the following code :

```
Sum
(
  (EXISTING 
    [TimeDim Transactions].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[date].MEMBERS)
 ,(
    ParallelPeriod
    (
      [TimeDim Transactions].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[month]
     ,1
     ,[TimeDim Transactions].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].CurrentMember
    )
   ,[Measures].[Net Amount]
  )
)
```

When I run the following query it works as expected.

```
SELECT 
  {
    NetAmountSamePeriodLastMonth
   ,[Measures].[net amount]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,[Stores Dim].[Store Code].Children ON ROWS
FROM [SalesDW_v1]
WHERE 
  {
    [TimeDim Transactions].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2014-12-04T00:00:00]
   ,[TimeDim Transactions].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2014-12-05T00:00:00]
  };
```

But when I browse the cube to get the same data with the same date filters It gives wrong numbers. The generated from browser mdx script is :

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Net Amount]
     ,[Measures].[NetAmountSamePeriodLastMonth]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {[Stores Dim].[Store Code].[Store Code].ALLMEMBERS}
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {
      [TimeDim Transactions].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2014-12-04T00:00:00]
     ,[TimeDim Transactions].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2014-12-05T00:00:00]
    } ON COLUMNS
  FROM [SalesDW_v1]
)
WHERE 
  [TimeDim Transactions].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].CurrentMember
CELL PROPERTIES 
  VALUE
 ,BACK_COLOR
 ,FORE_COLOR
 ,FORMATTED_VALUE
 ,FORMAT_STRING
 ,FONT_NAME
 ,FONT_SIZE
 ,FONT_FLAGS;
```

Something more, the browser shows correct numbers when one date is selected.

Is there a way to modify the calculated member in order to work correctly at the browser. I present the data on a power view report, but what i get is the incorrect numbers I see at the browser.

Below the code generated by browser when I use only one date member :

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    { [Measures].[Net Amount]
     ,[Measures].[NetAmountSamePeriodLastMonth] 
    } 

    ON COLUMNS 
    ,NON EMPTY 
    { ([Stores Dim].[Store Code].[Store Code].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
    DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 

   FROM 
       ( 
        SELECT (
                {[TimeDim Transactions].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2014-12-05T00:00:00] } 
               ) ON COLUMNS 

  FROM [SalesDW_v1]
       )
  WHERE ( [TimeDim Transactions].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2014-12-05T00:00:00] ) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR
, FORMATTED_VALUE
, FORMAT_STRING
, FONT_NAME
, FONT_SIZE
, FONT_FLAGS
```

Comment: 1) When you say wrong, how wrong is that? Is that a close figure or a weirdly large figure? 2) Please paste the MDX generated when you use only one date.

Comment: It is a weirdly large figure. I expect ~30000 and I get ~1600000. I edited the question to provide the code generated by the browser when I use only one date member. Thanks

Comment: I expected this. Will give a reply soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the scope(for `[TimeDim Transactions]` dimension) is not getting set correctly when you are having two dates in filter. But, in case of single date, the scope sets correctly, and hence the answer matches.

**When one date is selected**

See the clause associated with slicer. It is `[TimeDim Transactions].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2014-12-05T00:00:00] )`

**When two dates are selected**

The slicer becomes:
    [TimeDim Transactions].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].CurrentMember

Note that a sub-select **does not** set a context. So when you say that you want to filter by `[TimeDim Transactions].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].CurrentMember`, you are not actually filtering at all, since the current member ins absence of scope is the `[All]` member. That's why you are having a *weirdly large figure*.

To get rid of the issue, try having the dates in the axes, as below, instead of slicer, so that the scope gets selected.

```
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {[Stores Dim].[Store Code].[Store Code].ALLMEMBERS} * 
    {
      [TimeDim Transactions].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2014-12-04T00:00:00]
     ,[TimeDim Transactions].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2014-12-05T00:00:00]
    }

  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand now where the problem is, but I also see that there is no way solving it because I cannot customize the query executed by the reporting tool (power view). Am I right?

Comment: As long as the filtering is happening on slicer, then no, it can't be done away with :(