# Filter Measure by reference date column

Tags: ssas, mdx

In my date dimension I have an attribute called CompareToDatekey which shows the date that should be used to compare measures through time. How can I build a calculated measure that will give the measure value for the compare date when I filter a particular primary date?

What I tried to do is to make a CompareTime dimension which has a referenced relation through the primary time dimension 
([time dim].[CompareToDatekey] -> [TimeDim CompareDate].[datekey]) 
and then use the following calculated member :

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[CompareAmount]
AS 
(
    Sum(EXISTING [TimeDim CompareDate].[datekey].children
    ,[Measures].[Net Amount])
)
```

But the result is the measure filtered by the primary date and not the compare date.

Some test data :

datekey  |  ComparedToDatekey

20150109  | 20141219

20150110  | 20141220

datekey |   NetAmount

20141219 |  1716648.85

20150110 |  2266777.12

20141220 |  2378598.98

20150109 |  1588123.89

I would like a calculated member which give the sum of net amount on 20141219:20141220 when I filter for 20150109:20150110

Comment: Can you give some sample data for the Date Dimension with the two attributes (primary date and compare to date) and also the Fact table, including the Net Amount and the value of the primary date key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not an option to link dimensions, since filtering one of them doesn't mean filtering another. Their connection is used only for mapping, but not during slicing-dicing.

I see only boring StrToMember solution:

That's my test numbers:
[image: CompareDate_1Initial]

Add property to the lowest level of Date dimension:
[image: CompareDate_2Property]

Show this property as a measure:
[image: CompareDate_3PropertyInMDX]

Finally, cover by StrToMember:
[image: CompareDate_4CompareAmount]

It works, but I personally don't like such dynamic manipulations.

Sure thing, this solution doesn't require additional dimension, just a property. Your case script is smth like this:

```
with member [Measures].[CompareAmount]
as (StrToMember("[time dim].[datekey].&["
+[time dim].[datekey].Properties("Compare Date")
+"]"),[Measures].[Amount])
```

Comment: To add a property, I add a rigid attribute relationship or is something different?

Comment: Yep, rigid property if changing this property is not planned. But if planned due to some business logic, it's better to use flexible. Performance degradation is not so high as necessity of full reprocess the dimension and cube(-s) after that.

Comment: I sum this member among multiple date members and I encounter the problem described in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629181/mdx-query-incosistent-with-cube-browser
Is there a way to specify the scope on the calculated member's definition? I wouldn't like to show dates on the rows in order the scope to be correctly evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[CompareAmount]
AS 
(
    SUM(
    EXISTS([TimeDim CompareDate].ComparedToDatekey.children, 
           EXISTING [TimeDim CompareDate].[datekey].children)
    ,[Measures].[Net Amount]
)
```

Comment: I tried to implement it also, but it gives me null also. I find out that I have wrong relation established (in dimension usage) between the date dimensions in the cube. What would you do?

Comment: Can you define "wrong relation"? What was wrong exactly with it? Have you tried troubleshooting?

Comment: There was problem in the logic because I expected the referenced dimension to be filtered by the intermediate dimension, which is the opposite from what can be done.  :(
If you had to implement the requirement I explain in the question, would you build some relation? And If you did so, which would be?

Comment: You mean `ComparedToDatekey` and `Datekey` are not having correct mapping? Is there a source table behind `TimeDim CompareDate` or a named query?

Comment: ComparedToDatekey and Datekey are columns of a table and I have made to dimensions from this table. There is no named query.

Comment: So you're worried the mapping is improper. Troubleshoot using the following query: `select [TimeDim CompareDate].ComparedToDatekey.children on 1,
[Measures].[Net Amount] ON 0
FROM [YourCube]
WHERE [TimeDim CompareDate].[datekey].&[20150109] 
//Does this yield you "20141219"`

Comment: No it doesn't...I would like the calculated member to yield "20141219" on a query like this : select [TimeDim].Datekey.children on 1, [Measures].[Previous Net Amount] ON 0 FROM [SalesDW_v1] WHERE [TimeDim].[datekey].&[20150109] . The timedim dimension is the primary time dimension. [TimeDim CompareDate] dimension is a help dimension I thought I could use to build the calculated member.